# Password prompt for public git repositories with git daemon - gitolite

Tags: gitolite, git

I try to setup a git server with gitolite and make some repositories public.

I installed gitolite, configured it for the user `git` and everything works fine. Permissions and UMask are set to 0027, to allow redmine to read within git repositories.

```
UMASK                           =>  0027
```

I installed the package git-daemon-run and added the following line :

```
repo myrepo
    RW+ = @users
    R = daemon
```

I adjusted the `--base-path` directive in /etc/sv/git-daemon/run file to the /home/git/repositories directory.

But when I launch the command `git clone git@gitserver.tld:myrepo` from an "anonymous" server, the server prompt for a passphrase (`git@gitserver.tld's password`) !

This happens also if I launch git daemon as a git user

```
 $ git daemon --base-path=/home/git/repositories --reuseaddr
```

My repo is not a public repo...

How to setup the server not to prompt for password ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: when I run git's client, I must connect using the git protocol.

```
 git clone git@gitserver.tld:myrepo #git through ssh protocol
 git clone git://gitserver.tld/myrepo #use of git protocol
```

The use of git protocol works like a charm !